# Delete row if value in 3rd column is in another text file

Tags: bash, unix

I have a long text file (**haplotypes.txt**) that looks like this:

```
19 rs541392352 55101281 A 0 0 ...
19 rs546022921 55106773 C T 0 ...
19 rs531959574 31298342 T 0 0 ...
```

And a simple text file (**positions.txt**) that looks like this:

```
55103603
55106773
55107854
55112489
```

If would like to remove all the rows where the third field is present in **positions.txt**, to obtain the following output:

```
19 rs541392352 55101281 A 0 0 ...
19 rs531959574 31298342 T 0 0 ...
```

I hope someone can help.

Comment: Have you tried something? There are many similar questions already which do the same using `awk` etc.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$ grep -vwFf positions.txt haplotypes.txt 
19 rs541392352 55101281 A 0 0 ...
19 rs531959574 31298342 T 0 0 ...
```

- `-f positions.txt`: read patterns from file
- `-v`: invert matches
- `-w`: match only complete words (avoid substring matches)
- `-F`: fixed string matching (don't interpret patterns as regular expressions)

This expects that only the third column looks like a long number. If the pattern happens to match the exact same word in one of the columns that aren't shown, you can get false positives. To avoid that, you'd have to use an awk solution filtering by column (see [andlrc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37704009/3266847)).

Comment: Doesn't this match lines from `positions.txt` anywhere in the file. eg: `a b c d e f g h i 55101281` And not just third column.

Comment: @andlrc Exactly - if OP's data does have long numbers later in the line, this might have false positives.

Answer (score 1):

With AWK:

```
awk 'NR == FNR{a[$0] = 1;next}!a[$3]' positions.txt haplotypes.txt
```

Breakdown:

```
NR == FNR { # If file is 'positions.txt'
  a[$0] = 1 # Store line as key in associtive array 'a'
  next      # Skip next blocks
}
!a[$3]      # Print if third column is not in the array 'a'
```